# why pageX of variable is undefined

Tags: javascript

I don't know why mMove is undefined. Here is sample of JS

```
function quotoesMove(mMove){
    var quotes = document.getElementById("quotes");
   var  mMove = quotes.pageX; 
    console.log(mMove);
}
function quotesClick(){
 var quotes = document.getElementById("quotes");
    var mClickY = quotes.pageX;
    var mMove;
    quotoesMove(mMove);
    console.log(mMove + "something")
    var mouseRoad = mMove - mClickY;

    if(mouseRoad>0){
        quotes.style.marginRightright = mouseRoad + "px";

    }
    else{
        quotes.style.marginLeft = mouseRoad*(-1) + "px";
    }
}
 document.getElementById("quotes").addEventListener("mousemove", quotoesMove);
 document.getElementById("quotes").addEventListener("click", quotesClick);
```

And here is a link to html, css and js on codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bREMYQ

Comment: 1: No link to any code found 2: Click the `<>` and add the code and css here instead

Comment: pageX is on an event, not an element which has offset

Comment: In `quotesClick`, you initialise `mMove` (so it's `undefined`). You then pass it to `quotoesMove`. Inside that function you  create a new variable also called `mMove`, lets call it `mMove2`, and that has _something_ assigned to it (code not provided, so no idea what you expect the value to be). You then console log `mMove2` - it might have a value, it might not, as no idea what `quotes.pageX` is, can't tell. Then, back in `quotesClick`, you use the original `mMove`, which is still `undefined`, and try to do sums. If you call `quotoesMove` directly, same but an event goes in, not `mMove`

Comment: @DanCouper - OP mistakenly thinks that the `document.getElementById("quotes");` has a pageX attribute